# Change Language Hotkeys reset for no reason (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, language, hotkeys

Hey I'm using Windows 10. I created some hotkeys to change the keyboard layout to a specific language: `Alt`+`Shift`+`1` changes the layout to language A, `Alt`+`Shift`+`2` changes it to language B. The steps I took are also described here [Link](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/keyboard-language-shortcut/#Modify%20or%20disable%20the%20default%20keyboard%20shortcut%20to%20change%20language%20in%20Windows%2010).

The steps I did are:

- Settings
- Devices
- Typing
- Advanced keyboard settings
- Input language hot keys
- Advanced key settings
- Change Key Sequence: to Language A and to Language B

The keyboard shortcuts works fine for a while. I think after I restart or hibernate the system (or maybe just after some time, not sure) the hotkeys reset as if they were never set in the first place.

Edit: This seems to be a bug indeed and is happening after rechanging a dozen times. Users who need a hotkey can use `Win` + `Space` to change the language (it's a little bit slower but gets the job done).

Comment: I encountered the exact same bug, on a brand new install of Win10 .